# javascript: google geo - map

Tags: javascript

i have the following map of the world:

```
<!--
  copyright (c) 2009 Google inc.

  You are free to copy and use this sample.
  License can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/faq/#license
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geomap']});

    function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addRows(6);
      data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
      data.setValue(0, 0, 'Germany');
      data.setValue(0, 1, 200);
      data.setValue(1, 0, 'United States');
      data.setValue(1, 1, 300);
      data.setValue(2, 0, 'Brazil');
      data.setValue(2, 1, 400);
      data.setValue(3, 0, 'Canada');
      data.setValue(3, 1, 500);
      data.setValue(4, 0, 'France');
      data.setValue(4, 1, 600);
      data.setValue(5, 0, 'RU');
      data.setValue(5, 1, 700);

      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));
      geomap.draw(data, null);
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

instead of displaying a map of the entire world i would like to know how to display just the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, set the [region option](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html#Configuration_Options) on the geomap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geomap']});

    function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addRows(6);
      data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
      data.setValue(1, 0, 'United States');
      data.setValue(1, 1, 300);

      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));

      var options = { region: 'us_metro' };
      geomap.draw(data, options);
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not quite sure why you are setting the popularity of other countries to just center on the US though.

Comment: jack where can i find a tutorial on this? i dont want any other countries besides the US and its sttates

Comment: then just use region: 'us_metro', in the code you supplied replace  geomap.draw(data, null); with the two lines I gave you.

Comment: that gives me all the counties and i do mean COUNTIES i just want the states, how do i do it?

Comment: It won't give you the states. The us_metro is region will give you the basic metropolitan areas of the United States. That appears to be as detailed as it will be.

Comment: To get the states use "US" instead of "us_metro" for region option